# htaccess domain alias to single page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

So I have a couple additional domains pointing to my site. One of them I'd like to go directly to a page. I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. I got a redirect loop error with this. What am I missing?

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.alias.com
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.alias.com/section/page/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.alias\.com$
Rewriterule ^/?$ /section/page/ [L]
```